# Keep escaped forward slashes in JSON string values with jq

Tags: jq

According to the JSON specification, forward slashes don't *have* to be escaped with a backslash but they *can* be.
I have a JSON file which has all forward slashes in string values escaped for compatibly reasons (but not inside the keys):

```json
{
  "proto://some/path": "\/\/some\/path"
}
```

However, `jq` automatically removes these backslashes:

```bash
$ echo '{"proto://some/path":"\/\/some\/path"}' | jq -c .
{"proto://some/path":"//some/path"}
```

I need the output to be `{"proto://some/path":"\/\/some\/path"}`

**How can I tell `jq` to NOT change any string values and keep these backslashes?**
Alternatively, is there a way to re-add these backslashes *only to the values* after it went through `jq`?

Comment: Are object keys and values the only places where strings are used? No array of strings for instance?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The structure of the JSON is arbitrarily nested and it has arrays of strings as well which also need to keep the escaped slash, yes. Good point.

Comment: Would whatever application that uses this understand the JSON string `a\\/b` (encoded) as `a\/b` (decoded) and be able to use it correctly?  If not, then there is no point in talking about JSON or using `jq` and instead treat the document as text and use `awk` to do whatever you need to do since the thing that is reading the document clearly isn't a JSON parser.  The thing with the string `a\/b` is that to a JSON application, that backslash does not exist.

Comment: I've updated my answer to escape  `/`s in strings except those used as object keys.

Comment: @Kusalananda It seems like it does indeed also work *without* the backslash in the programs I tested. However, since this is a somewhat standardized file format, I didn't want to change the encoding incase it breaks something somewhere. I only used `jq` to sort the keys with `--sort-keys` since the tool that generated these files produced a non-deterministic order which messed up my `git` diffs.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas provided (as usual!) a good and flexible answer, but I am curious as to why you need to have `\/` instead of `/` in your data in the first place? `/`is not a special character in regex. One possible reason would be for exemple if you use that to create awk code, and use : `/pattern/`, and dont want any '/' inside pattern to be interpreted as the end of the `/.../` ? But you could replace it with `$0 ~ "pattern"` (or `$0 ~ pattern_in_variable` ) ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac see comments to Kusalananda's answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, your so link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580682, and its answers) are very informative!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be surprised if you could. `jq` decodes its input, does its operations and encodes the resulting object as json. Upon encoding and outputting, it outputs those strings encoded in JSON and the information that there were `\`s in front of `/`s has long been lost. Same would happen if those `/`s where initially written `\u002f`. You'll find that `jq` also reformats `1.0` as `1`, `1e2` as `100`, `INF` as `1.7976931348623157e+308`, etc for the same reason.

However, JSON is a relatively easy file format to process reliably by hand using for instance perl regexps.

To add back the `\`s before each `/` in all strings except those that are object keys, you could do:

```
jq... |
  perl -0777 -pe '
    s{"(?:\\.|.)*?"(\s*:)?}{
      $1 ? $& : $& =~ s{/}{\\/}gr
    }ge'
```

Which should work correctly even if you have strings embedding `"`s and `\`s (like `{"key": "//\"//\\"}`).

As an alternative to `jq`, you could use the JSON::PP `perl` module which can be told to escape slashes (though would be in all strings though):

```
$ json_pp -json_opt escape_slash < your-file
{"proto:\/\/some\/path":"\/\/some\/path"}
```

If you're already familiar with `perl`, the learning curve would be less steep than having to learn the `jq` syntax.

In any case while the JSON format allows `/`s to be escaped as `\/` (or `\u002f` like for any character) those don't need to. From what I read online, that's allowed so one can embed a JSON string containing `</` in an HTML `<script>` tag by writing it `"<\/whatever"`. That's why some JSON encoders encode those `\/` as `/` as that makes it more portable. But if that JSON is not meant to be embedded as is in HTML, it probably doesn't matter. And if it were, you'd likely want to have that encoding everywhere including in object keys.

Comment: That `perl` magic seems to work with all files I've tested so far, wow! Thanks.

Comment: If this isn't a one-time oepration, I would rewrite that Perl fragment to something less exotic ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that some process that isn't aware of the need for encoding strings in JSON has inserted the literal string they think they need to store, without encoding it.  Since the backslashes are escaping characters that don't need escaping, and since no backslashes are escaping the literal backslashes themselves, they will appear to  "disappear" when `jq` is used to extract and decode the string or when it processes the document for other reasons.

In short, the *forward* slashes don't have to be escaped (escaping them is effectively a no-op), but backslashes need to be if you want to keep them as literal backslashes.

The following will change each `/` into `\\/` (which is how you write `\/` in a JSON string) in all string values in your document, recursively. Remember, when the `jq` expression is processing the data, the `jq` parser has already removed the backslashes.

```bash
jq 'walk(if type == "string" then gsub("/"; "\\/") else . end)' file
```

For the given example document, this would generate

```json
{
  "proto://some/path": "\\/\\/some\\/path"
}
```

Extracting and decoding the encoded string value from the modified document would give you `\/\/some\/path`:

```bash
$ jq 'walk(if type == "string" then gsub("/"; "\\/") else . end)' file | jq -r '."proto://some/path"'
\/\/some\/path
```

You would arrive at the same JSON document if you created it from scratch like so:

```bash
$ jq -n --arg 'proto://some/path' '\/\/some\/path' '$ARGS.named'
{
  "proto://some/path": "\\/\\/some\\/path"
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that the OP wants the *JSON output* to have `/`s in those strings escaped as `\/` (allowed in JSON, see [JSON: why are forward slashes escaped?](//stackoverflow.com/a/1580682))

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm thinking a process that is not JSON-aware has inserted the literal string into the JSON document without encoding it. This causes the backslashes to "disappear" when the string is extracted with `jq`.

Comment: `\/`, `\u002f` and `/` are 3 valid encodings of a `/` in JSON strings. `printf '%s\n' '["/", "\/", "\u002f"]' | jq -c` outputs `["/","/","/"]`, the OP would like the original encoding to be preserved.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas My point is that the string probably wasn't JSON-encoded when inserted into the document (possibly through injecting a shell variable directly into a text string). I'm assuming they want the `\/` to be retained as `\/` when extracting it from the document.

Comment: That's also speculation on my part, but I don't think so. The "compatibly reasons" suggests those `/` were intentionally escaped as `\/` as is apparently common. See the SO link I gave above.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The user absolutely escapes the slash for a reason, but it's likely that this is for whatever application they need to finally use that string in. To store it in a JSON string, it has to be _additonally_ encoded, which they (or someone) forgot or did not think about.

Comment: See for instance: `php -r 'echo json_encode("/");'`. As mentioned there, a reason to want `/`s to be escaped is when the json is embedded in HTML `<script>` tags, though here it rather looks like it's about feeding that json to some software that expects escaped slashes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Related on-point comment elsewhere: [How to remove backslash on json\_encode() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/19860740)

Comment: To add some context: These are JSON files generated as part of Apple's [Xcode DocC documentation archive format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-documentation-to-external-developers) which is viewable in a browser. I don't know exactly how it works but I think it's something along what @StéphaneChazelas mentioned, the JSON is probably read by JavaScript and embedded in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem, I do indeed need the output JSON to have "\/" not "\\/". I also tried `gsub("/"; "\/")` but that produces just "/".

Comment: @YourMJK Ok, so whatever is reading this is not a JSON parser, which means you might just as well drop the use of `jq` and use `awk` or whatever other text processor to work with this data.

Comment: @Kusalananda Hence the second part of my question, whether this would alternatively be possible using a different tool if `jq` can't do it. I couldn't figure out how to only target the values and not the keys for the replacing using text processors.

Comment: FYI, PHP's `json_encode()` escapes forward slash by default (you have to use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag to disable it). So it's probably not true that this JSON wasn't properly JSON-encoded.